# Using data received in props in a template (vue)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

In this code:

```
<template>
  <div class="inventory-section-component">
    <draggable v-model="itemSectionData.itemSectionCategory">
      <transition-group>
        <div
          v-for="category in itemSectionData.itemSectionCategory"
          :key="category.itemSectionCategoryId"
        >
          <!-- <p>{{ category.itemSectionCategoryName }}</p>  -->
          <inventory-section-group-component :itemSectionGroupProps="category">
          </inventory-section-group-component>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InventorySectionGroupComponent from "./inventorySectionGroupC";
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  name: "InventorySectionComponent",
  components: {
    inventorySectionGroupComponent,
    draggable,
  },
  props: {
    itemSectionProps: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      default() {
        return { itemSectionCategory: {} };
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      itemSectionData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.itemSectionProps))
    };
  },  
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

through some struggle, I've come to know that `itemSectionData` in

```
<draggable v-model="itemSectionData.itemSectionCategory">
```

is **NOT**  the same as `itemSectionData` in "data()":

```
  data() {
    return {
      itemSectionData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.itemSectionProps))
    };
  },
```

How can I get stuff into `itemData` from props and use it in the component's template?

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but the value passed to JSON.stringify() in data() should be ```this.itemSectionProps```, not ```this.props.itemSectionProps```.

Comment: Tried all variations imaginable. No luck :(

Comment: Could you be running into the old problem of reactive data in Vue 2 - where you are changing the `itemSectionProps` somewhere (like in the parent component) but aren't getting reactive results?

Also I wonder if your data structure could more easily work for you if you use an array for the loop instead of an object - just an idea, probably not helpful ;)

Last thing- why don't you use the itemSectionProps property directly - why make the copy? Maybe some explanation could help us out. Thanks!